# Nvidia driver boot issues AMD iGPU, idle temperature fluctuations

Tags: nvidia, kernel, temperature, amdgpu, nouveau

Asus ROG G15 Laptop
AMD Ryzen 7 4800hs
Nvidia 1660ti (TU116M)
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
6.2.0-10110gcp/6.2.0-26-generic

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my laptop, fresh install dual booting Windows 11.

I was getting issues with temperature whilst idling and fans going on and off all the time (typically on Windows they only come on when the GPU is in use). I couldn't get any sensor data working, but found  $ watch acpi -t to be fluctuating wildly around 50-75oC.

This made me attempt to install the NVIDIA drivers from the default Nouveau. I tried the Software centre and selected nvidia-driver-525. After the reboot, I can only get a black display, even in recovery mode, adding nomodeset etc under kernal 6.2.0-10110gcp.

I then tried the same with 6.2.0-26-generic and managed to boot, followed the instructions I could find, purged the drivers and installed the Nvidia recommended one (535).

I really have no idea how I've got here after so many reboots, but my system is currently booting great under the 26-generic, and the temperature is stable around 41oC, a coincidence I'm not sure. I'm just not really sure what has happened and why the other kernel isn't working, or what the difference is between generic and gcp. The only thing I can see online is that it may be a Google Cloud Platform version, in which case, I have no idea how I have ended up with it during the automated installation process.

Is there anything obvious I am missing here, can I remove the latest kernel from grub?